# Call a function stored inside a map

Tags: scala

I have a Map that I would like to create like this :

```
val mapCastMethods = Map("Integer" -> toInt)
```

And then I would like to call the method repviously stored with the map.
Something like :

```
"345".mapCastMethods("Integer")
```

How can I do that ?

Answer (score 3):

I think something like this should work :

```
  val toInt = (x: String) => x.toInt

  val mapCastMethods = Map("Integer" -> toInt)


  val res = mapCastMethods("Integer")("345") // [EDIT] Same as val res= mapCastMethods.get("Integer").get(("345"))

  println(res) // 345
```

You should define function literal of the toInt func :)

Comment: it's ok, but could be a bit optimized: `val result:Int = mapCastMethods("Integer")("345")`

Comment: I was solving the same problem for relational operators in scala just now. Nice to know this approach

Answer (score 1):

```
type Cast[A, X] = A => X
type CastMethods[K, A, X] = Map[K, Cast[A, X]]

implicit def cast[K, A, X](implicit methods: CastMethods[K, A, X]): 
    K => A => X
  = k => a => methods(k)(a)
```

Then usage:

```
sealed trait CastMethod
case object Integer extends CastMethod
implicit val methods: CastMethods[CastMethod, String, Int] 
  = Map(Integer -> (_ : String).toInt)

cast.apply(Integer)("345")
```

Comment: it's a nice abstraction, but what if you want to add a cast from e.g. `Set` to `List`? Your type parameter `X` is already bound to `Int`.
Will you need to declare then one more implicit val and every time for a new cast instantiate a new `Map` with a single element in it?

Comment: I think I understand. It will be `implicit val methods: CastMethods[CastMethod, Any, Any] 
  = Map(Integer -> (_ : String).toInt, Set -> (_:Set).toList)`